# Roundup after decimal in awk in solaris os

Tags: shell, unix, awk, solaris, solaris-10

I want total size of file  in a folder using certain file starting with name like abc_1_* in sun solaris os because here i cannot use du -ch, current i am using find command i am getting required output but i want round up output after decimal

Current code :-

```
echo `find $DUMPDIR -name "${DUMPFILE}*" -exec ls -ltr {} \;  | awk ' {s+=$5} END {print s/1024/1024/1024}'`
```

output:-

```
  1.768932
```

Desired  output:-

```
1.7G
```

Kindly help me with this i am new to solaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find $DUMPDIR -name "${DUMPFILE}*" -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{print $5}'
```

You can use GNU extension `-h` option for `ls` to print sizes in human readable format. Note: as suggested by @Andrew Henle, **`-h` is not guaranteed to be supported in `ls`.**

Or simply use,

```
ls -lh "$DUMPDIR/${DUMPFILE}*" | cut -d' ' -f 5
```

Comment: *You can directly use the `-h` option for `ls` to print sizes in human readable format.* No, you can't. `-h` is a GNU extension to the [standardized `ls` arguments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) and it is not guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: I am getting 0 GB output

Comment: echo `find $DUMPDIR -name "${DUMPFILE}*" -exec ls -lh {} \;  | awk ' {s+=$5} END {print s/1024/1024/1024}'` "GB"

Comment: Just use `awk '{print $5}'` is enough.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, thanks for your information, I'll try to modify my answer to highlight this.

Comment: @CWLiu If the questioner is lucky, he's got a late-enough version of Solaris that *does* support `-h`, or his Solaris install has GNU `ls` installed somewhere.  This question's answers cover the various locations that the GNU utilities might be installed:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools

Answer (score 0):

You can round up a float in `awk` with

```
awk 'BEGIN {fl=1.768932; printf("%.1f G\n", fl)}'
```